# Most efficient way to get lists?

Tags: sql, mysql

What's the best way to get a sublist of things?

I have two tables:

```
create table A (
  id int primary key
)

create table B (
  id int primary key,
  aid int foreign key references A( id ),
  sort_key int
)
```

I want to get a list of objects A, with subobjects B, but only the top five of B.

Let's say A is people, and B is type of food, with sort_key being how much a person likes that food.  How do I get everybody (or some people) and their top 5 food?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the previous comment if it's an INT you can't put non numerics in there.

Assuming the following data:

```
a
--
id
1
2
3

b
------------------------
id    aid   sort_key
1    1     1
2    1     2
3    2     1
4    3     1
5    1     3
6    1     4
7    1     5
8    1     6
9    2     2
10  2     3
```

The following query in MySQL would give you this:

```
SELECT a.*,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS ids FROM b AS bi WHERE bi.aid = a.id ORDER BY sort_key LIMIT 5) AS ids
FROM a
```

Result:

```
id   ids
1   1,2,5,6,7,8
2   3,9,10
3   4
```

Comment: you have a typo somewhere (id=1 has 6 ids) but thanks!  This is actually very close to what I need!

Answer (score 1):

This query assumes the sort key is one based, rather than zero:

```
  SELECT a.name
         b.food
    FROM A a
    JOIN B b ON b.aid = a.id
   WHERE b.sortkey <= 5
ORDER BY a.name, b.sortkey
```

Comment: thanks, but sort_key could be anything, and not numbered, though I can preprocess the data to do something like that.

Comment: You'd have problems putting data that's not numeric based on your modelling - currently the column is an int ;)

Comment: sorry, didn't mean non-numeric, but not strictly 1,2,3,4,5, which appears to be your logic

Comment: Change the WHERE b.sortkey to use a BETWEEN if you can hardcode the values, or use a JOIN (preferable to a subselect).